# Non-EU citizen moving from Germany to the Netherlands - partner and 'home' stay in Germany - residence and tax questions

Tags: germany, taxes, dependent-visa, non-citizens

I'm a non-EU citizen, currently in possession of a Niederlassungserlaubnis. My partner has a residence permit that states §30 Abs. 1 (immigration of spouse).

I plan to move to the Netherlands for a new job, and will get a NL residence + work visa for highly skilled migrants. My partner plans to continue living and working in Germany. Partner's salary is above the blue card limit in Germany, and I'm currently on my partner's health insurance as a non-working spouse.

We're looking for good tax and immigration lawyers to speak with, but would love some initial answers to these questions:

1. Can I avoid deregistering in Germany (abmeldung) since my partner will keep our current apartment and I'll be here almost every weekend? We consider this to be our primary home.
2. If I don't deregister,
   2a. will my Niederlassungserlaubnis remain valid?
   2b. what should we do about our tax categories?
3. My partner's visa expires later this year. Can they apply for a new one that isn't dependent on a spouse visa, rather one that stands on it's own - blue card / niederlassungserlaubnis?
4. If I do deregister, can I revive my niederlassungserlaubnis if I come back to Germany in 2 years or so? I've emailed the foreigners office about an exception, but haven't received a reply and probably won't get a chance to speak with them before I leave.